# ASP.NET -> Synchronous call to a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm in need of a synchronous call from code-behind ASP.NET (C#) to a Javascript function.

I've tried the ScriptManager.Registerclient, but as this is asynchronous this is no good. I'm in need of some testing in javascript before returning a value (updating an UpdatePanel) to check whether or not the operation is valid.

For a short code example:

```
myButton_click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  <callJavascriptSynchronous>
  if (MyHiddenField.Value == "true")
     //Do
else
   //Don't
}
```

MyHiddenField is within an UpdatePanel. For the javascript function:

```
function javascriptFoo(myInteger)
{
  var returnValue = window.external.TestInteger(myInteger);
  document.getElementById('<%=MyHiddenField.ClientID%>').value = returnValue;
}
```

The UpdatePanel looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" Visible="false"/>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Any suggestions on the synchronous call?

Thanks!

Edit: Added full code:

MyPage.aspx:

```
function javascriptFoo(myInteger)
{
  var returnValue = window.external.TestInteger(myInteger);
  document.getElementById('<%=MyHiddenField.ClientID%>').value = returnValue;
}

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" Visible="false"/>
</ContentTemplate>
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

MyPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelContext, UpdatePanelContext.GetType(), "AlertTest", "AlertTest()", true);

   string sVal = HiddenFieldContext.Value;

   if (sVal == "true") //do
   else //don't
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're in your button's click-event, you've already left the frontend and cannot jump back for a function call. Execute the function first, clientside, upon the button-click (read about the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event), then return your result with the postback.

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1456473.aspx) addresses the same issue.

Comment: Postback will do me no good, as this is happening within an operation. I'm actually doing this within a GridView.RowCommand event.

Comment: Where is `myButton_click`?

Comment: Where it is? 
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">

I'm in need of testing the data within the Gridview_rowCommand event.

I am able to do this, and it works, but the call is not synchronous.

Comment: Is `myButton_click` in your frontend JavaScript or in your backend C#?

Comment: The function declaration is back-end.

Comment: So how do you expect a frontend JavaScript function to be called on the backend? I may have misunderstood the question entirely.

Comment: You might have. I'm able to use ScriptManager.Registerclient(this.Page, this.GetType(), "javascriptFoo", String.Format("javascriptFoo('{0}');", "11111"), true);

This calls the javascript asynchronous, and I cannot wait back-end for the response. This is my issue, as I need the response before I know whether to continue back-end code or not.

Comment: It does not call a JavaScript function asynchronous. It puts the JavaScript into the page, which is then executed after the postback. 
You think you are executing JavaScript and you are exepcting results from it before it even reaches the client. 
That won't work at all. You cannot call frontend JavaScript while you are in the backend.

Comment: Added full code listing.

Would you happen to have any other suggestion on how to solve the issue at hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Lot's of things. You could bring the `TestInteger` logic to the backend. But whatever it does, just have it perform clientside before the postback happens, like I suggest in my answer. What DOES it do?

Comment: The ASP.NET application is running in an C# WebBrowser application. It checks some other integrations in that application, and returns a value if the ASP.NET application shoud be able to continue or not.